# Is it possible to write a maximum of $n$ variables $\max(x_1,...,x_n)$ as a sum of maximum of two variables $\max(a,b)+\max(c,d)+...$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

See Question above;
In my case it holds that $x_1,...,x_n$ are real numbers and of course $a,b,...$ are not allowed to be calculated based on a maximum or minimum (such that we end up with a nested maximum) but by some smooth function, most likely a linear combination od the input variables

Comment: It depends on the way $a,b,c,d,\dots$ may depend on $x_1,x_2,\dots$. For instance if $a=\max(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $b=a-1$, then
$$\max(a,b) = \max(x_1,\dots, x_n).$$

Comment: Sorry, my bad; Obviously no nested maxima (or minima) are allowed

Comment: No. Consider the case of $3$ variables: $a>b>c$. Assume you have an expression $s(a,b,c)$ made using linear combinations of maxima and minima of two variables that gives you the maximum of all $3$. The expression must be symmetric in $a,b,c$, so you have only $2$ components: $max(a,b)+max(b,c)+max(c,a) = 2a + b$ and $min(a,b)+min(b,c)+min(c,a) = 2c+ b$.  We may also add the sum of all vars, $a+b+c$. No linear combination of these values  can give $a$.